# Passing a grid to a function used to export to excel

Tags: asp.net, grid

I have a method that is used to export the data to excel.Till now I have been passing table to the method.But now I wish to pass the grid data so that I do not have to call the procedures for different instances for getting different filtered data sets.
is there a way to do so?

```
    public void ExportToExcel(DataSet ds)
    {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            string filename = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["filename"].ToString() + ".xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
            dgGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dgGrid.DataBind();
            //Get the HTML for the control.
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            //Write the HTML back to the browser.
            //Response.ContentType = application/vnd.ms-excel;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Concat("attachment;filename=", filename));
            Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            // this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

This is the method that I am using to export to excel.

Comment: You want to Export a Dataset to an Excel file? If you I can show you the Code

Comment: What I want is that I fill a datatable with whatever is in the grid(that has already been filled with another datatable for which I had to call a method).I want to avoid calling the methods as for different conditions i need to call different methods (different table).I want to simplify..as once I fill the grid..the same stuff I want to be passed to exportToExcel method which works on click..I cant even call the ExportToExcel method each time I fill the grid. Thus the problem

Comment: So why don't you just export the grid into excel?